# How to use command-line tool `openssl` to decrypt ciphertext encripted by Perl module Crypt::DES?

Tags: perl, encryption, openssl, cryptography

How to use command-line tool `openssl` to decrypt the ciphertext that was encrypted with Perl module Crypt::DES?

Assume we have a Perl script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use 5.010;
use Getopt::Long qw(:config no_ignore_case);
use Crypt::CBC;
### initialization
&GetOptions("mode=s" => \(my $mode = ''));
my $secret = q/;[qO7e<_sZmR8Krhf>}]mRY`y)BI8"WEF*2nmL^o'WMKA=uEt1/;
my $key = pack('H*', $secret);
open(my $fh, '>', 'key.bin');
$fh->print($key);
$fh->close();
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -key => $key, -cipher => 'DES'
);
### read file
my $filename = shift @ARGV;
open($fh, '<', $filename) or die "$!";
my $cchRead = read($fh, my $buffer, -s $fh);
close($fh);
die "$!" unless defined($cchRead);
### encrypt
if ($mode eq 'encrypt') {
    print $cipher->encrypt($buffer);
}
### decrypt
else {
    print $cipher->decrypt($buffer);
}
```

We can use the Perl script like:

```
$ ./cipher.pl --mode=encrypt foo.txt > foo.encrypted # Encrypt plaintext.
$ ./cipher.pl --mode=decrypt foo.encrypted # Decrypt ciphertext.
```

My question is how to decrypt foo.encrypted with command-line tool `openssl`?
I've tried these commands but in vain.

```
$ openssl enc -des          -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-cbc      -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-cfb      -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-cfb1     -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-cfb8     -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-ecb      -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-ede      -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-ede-cbc  -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-ede-cfb  -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-ede-ofb  -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-ede3     -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-ede3-cbc -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-ede3-cfb -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-ede3-ofb -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des-ofb      -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -des3         -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -desx         -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
$ openssl enc -desx-cbc     -salt -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -d -in 'foo.encrypted'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my machine, decryption of the ciphertext generated with the Perl script is successful with:

```
openssl enc -des -md md5 -pass file:key.bin -d -in foo.encrypted
```

`-des` is equivalent to `-des-cbc` and specifies DES in CBC mode. No PBKDF2 is used as key derivation function, but the OpenSSL proprietary `EVP_BytesToKey()` with MD5 as digest. The expected ciphertext is the concatenation of the ASCII encoding of `Salted__`, followed by an 8 bytes salt, followed by the actual ciphertext.

Regarding security: DES, `EVP_BytesToKey()` and MD5 are deprecated and insecure (better choose AES, PBKDF2 and SHA-256).

---

As a side note, `encrypt()` returns the `raw` ciphertext, therefore with Windows the data must be output in binary (e.g. with `binmode(STDOUT)`) so that the ciphertext is not corrupted by CRLF⇔LF conversions. Alternatively, the ciphertext can be output Base64 encoded (in which case the `-a` option must be set in the OpenSSL statement).

Comment: Thank you. One more question. If we add `-pbkdf => 'pbkdf2'` to the ctor of `$cipher`, how do we decrypt it with command-line tool `openssl`? I've tried `openssl enc -d -des-cbc -pbkdf2 -pass file:key.bin -in ciphertext` but only got "bad descrypt" and garbled codes. Thanks.

Comment: If the cipher is blowfish, i.e. `-cipher => 'Blowfish'`, why `openssl enc -d -bf-cbc -md md5 -pass file:key.bin -in ciphertext` doesn't work? It's so confusing. How do you know which C functions are the counterpart, and which command-line options shall be used? Thanks.

Comment: Just found my version is 2.33 that seemingly supports only MD5 key derivation algorithm, so please ignore the 1st comment, but I still don't get it why `-bf-cbc -md md5` doesn't work like `-des -md md5`.

Comment: @Cody - This seems to be a Blowfish specific issue (e.g. AES also works besides DES). [Blowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)) has a *variable* keysize between 32 and 448 bits. The internal key derivation via `EVP_BytesToKey()` in Perl uses a keysize of 448 bits (`$crypt->keysize()`), while OpenSSL uses 128 bits (`-p` option), s. also [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/25405). Thus, both are incompatible.